# statechangestart prevent from navigating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState  , toParams
                                                   , fromState, fromParams) {
     if(fromState.name=='home' && toState.name == 'search'){
         event.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

I am trying to prevent the state transitioning from happening.

```
event.preventDefault()
```

is not doing that.
I want the state to remain in the current one.

Comment: Should works, what do you trying to do ?

Comment: i dont want the state to change, when the if condition is true.

Comment: lol thanks, but, who trigger the event ? Maybe you have another item the re-trigger the stateChange ?
Are you sure that the if statement is true?

Comment: i am on the state 'home', i click on a link that takes me to state 'search'. that makes the if statement true. i checked. there is no other stateChange trigger happening.

Comment: I have found a plnkr that works fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/3tRKtG?p=preview

Comment: hi, thanks for the responses. i had the if statement inside a promise. i guess that's why it was not working as expected. now it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you require, should be working out of the box. I created [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u8XhJv9uMR1QCvc3iCr4?p=preview), showing your requirement in action. There are these three sample states

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        template: '<div>home</div>',
      })
    .state('search', {
        url: '/search',
        template: '<div>search</div>',
      })
    .state('index', {
        url: '/index',
        template: '<div>index</div>',
      })
```

And this (the same as in question) condition DISABLES navigation from HOME to SEARCH:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
   function(event, toState  , toParams
                   , fromState, fromParams) 
    {
      var isFromHome = fromState.name =='home' ;
      var isToSearch = toState.name == 'search';
      if(isFromHome && isToSearch)
      {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u8XhJv9uMR1QCvc3iCr4?p=preview)

Comment: thanks Radim. i had put the if statement in the wrong place.  will the state transition wait for a promise to be fulfilled and then navigate to that state?

Comment: I would say yes. The state is always waiting for resolve to happen.. Great if that helped anyhow. Enjoy UI-Router